# Getting size of FXML generated nodes

Tags: javafx

I want to get the size of a node, after it has been sized properly, which I understand is done after the stage is shown. however, i cannot do it in start() method, because the node is not initialized yet, because its loaded it from an FXML file.

If I implement Initializable Interface and try to get the size in initialize() method, it returns 0.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="musicPlayer.Test">
<columnConstraints>
<ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
</columnConstraints>
<rowConstraints>
<RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
</rowConstraints>
<children>
  <TableView fx:id="testNode">
    <columns>
      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
    </columns>
  </TableView>
</children>
</GridPane>
```

just an arbitrary node in a grid pane generated with scene builder

```
public class Test extends Application implements Initializable {
@FXML
private TableView testNode;

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    //System.out.println(testNode.getWidth()); is always 0.0 
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("test.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    //System.out.println(testNode.getWidth()); throws Nullpointer Exception
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

I've also tried adding a listener to the stage, but i still get a nullpointer exception.
Is there a way of getting the size, without using a sleeping thread?

Comment: Why do you need its size?

Comment: And, of course you get a `NullPointerException` from the code you commented out: `testNode` is never initialized in the instance on which `start(...)` is called.

Comment: `Pane.getPrefWidth()` ???

Comment: I need its size because I need to calculate how many of another node can fit in there, specifically i want to create an album artwork view for my music player. I cant use pref width, because i need it to be resizable.

Comment: So typically you would just use a [predefined layout pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) to manage something like that. E.g. a `FlowPane` or `TilePane`, etc. If none of those work (which is unlikely), you can just register a listener or bind to the [`widthProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#widthProperty) (etc) of the control. (Or of course create your own layout pane, by subclassing `Pane` and overriding `layoutChildren`: that is quite hard though.)

Comment: that will probably do it, thank you :)